# StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have created a function in one of the protractor pages. On clicking the function takes me to the another page for which i have used require keyword.

```
this.naviagteToSwaggerOrReadme = function(str) {

  this.endpointDropdown.click();
  browser.sleep(2000);
  //element(by.partialLinkText('swagger/index.html')).click();
  element(
     by.className('popover ng-scope ng-isolate-scope bottom fade in')
  )
  .all(by.tagName('a')).then(function(obj) {

    console.log('Number of elements with the a tag in the parent element is ' + obj.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      obj[i].getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log('The text on the link  is ' + text);
        var linkText = text;

        if (linkText.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) !== -1) {
          obj[i].click();
        } else {
          obj[i + 1].click();
        }
      })
    }

  });

  browser.sleep(5000);
  return require('./Swagger.js');
};
```

I am invoking the same function .

```
swagger = appsPageOne.naviagteToSwaggerOrReadme('swagger');
        swagger.getSwaggerTitle().then(function(title){
            console.log('This is the title '+title);
        })
```

But I am getting the error as :

```
 Message:
    Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.6)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
  Stack:
    StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: `obj[i].click();` in for loop leads to current page changed, the next `obj.click()` not work on the  page where found it. So report `StaleElementReferenceError`

Comment: Is there a way i can break out and return the next page ..i used break..return in the loop but no luck

Comment: Do you want to only click the first matched `<a>` or click all matched `<a>` one by one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Read text of all found links via `element.all().getText()`
2. Find out the index of matched link by comparing link's text with parameter: `str`
3. Search all links again and click the matched one via `element.all().get(index)`
4. Put `return require('./Swagger.js');` inside `then()`, otherwise `return` statement executed prior to clicking on matched link.

Changed code as following:

```
this.naviagteToSwaggerOrReadme = function(str) {

  this.endpointDropdown.click();
  browser.sleep(2000);

  let links = element.all(
     by.css('.popover.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope.bottom.fade.in a')
  )

  return links.getText().then(function(txts) {

    let size = txts.length;

    console.log('Number of elements with the a tag in the parent element is ' + size);

    let index = txts.findIndex(function(txt){
      return txt.toLowerCase().includes(str);
    });

    if(index === -1) {
      index = size - 1;
    }

    links.get(index).click();
    browser.sleep(5000);

    return require('./Swagger.js');
  });

};
```

`naviagteToSwaggerOrReadme()` return a promise, thus you need to consume the returned `swagger` in then()

```
appsPageOne.naviagteToSwaggerOrReadme('swagger').then(function(swagger){
  swagger.getSwaggerTitle().then(function(title){
      console.log('This is the title '+title);
  });
});
```